# Managing files on Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I have a git repository that stores audio files.

Obviously, it's not the best usage of git, and the repo has become quite large.

As an alternative, I would like to be able to manipulate these audio files at the command line, "commiting" when some work is done.

Is this type of context possible with manipulating Amazon S3 files at the command line?

Or do you `scp`, for example, files to S3?

Answer (score 1):

There are some rsync tools to S3 that may work for you, here is an example which I have not tried: http://www.s3rsync.com/

How important are the older versions of the audio? Amazon S3 buckets can have 'versioning' turned on, and you get full versioning support. You pay full $ for each version - I don't know if you have 10 GB or 10TB to store, and your budget, etc... The amazon versioning is nice, but there are not a lot of tools that fully support it.

Comment: [Cloud Combine](http://www.gapotchenko.com/cloudcombine) supports Amazon S3 versioning in an intuitive way. Check out the Cloud Combine documentation pages on [working with file versions](http://www.gapotchenko.com/cloudcombine/documentation/working-with-file-versions-in-amazon-s3-versioned-bucket) and [working with deleted files](http://www.gapotchenko.com/cloudcombine/documentation/viewing-and-restoring-deleted-files-in-amazon-s3-versioned-bucket).

Answer (score 0):

To manipulate S3 files you will first have to download it and then upload it when you are done, this is relatively simple to do.

However, if the amount of files you have is truly large, the slow transfer rate and bandwidth charge will kill you. If you don't have that much files, DropBox is built on top of S3 and have syncing and a rudimentary version control, bandwidth is not charged..

I felt like using a good networked storage system and git on your LAN is still the better idea.

Comment: When you say "good storage system", you're not referring to Amazon S3, right? Instead, you're saying to host a git repository whereever I can support it (on a server for example).

Comment: I am saying something like a networked storage device on your local LAN. Any servers will impose a lot of latency and bandwidth charges, is there a reason you want to use a remote storage?

Comment: The reason for having it on Amazon S3 would be to sever the files on a web site. Currently, they are also hosted on my web server (synchronised through the git repository) and served on the web site. I manipulate the files on my local computer, which makes git useful for synchronisation.